# MapOverLay Not Staying consistently like MapMarker On Android SDK

Tags: android, maps, here-api

I am Drawing preview of the Route and Wanted to show TTD(Time to Destination) as a Info Along with Route at Center(I know Center of the Route) of the Route.

I used MapOverlay to achieve this , but some time The MapOverlay is not sitting at GeoLocation
[Please find Image for better Understanding.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/475nF.png)

Partial Solution:
Wait Until MapDrwan then apply MapOverlay but I don't know When Drawing is completed.

Comment: Do you use MapFragment or MapView? Do you use MapOverlay.setManualRefresh(false)? Which device do you use? Would be nice if you share snippet of code how you use overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the question is related to HERE Android Premium SDK  3.14, Using MapOverlay.setManualRefresh() should solve the issue of MapOverlay floating around specially after a screen rotation.

For detecting map draw completion there is a callbacks available in SDK namely :

```
m_mapFragment.addOnMapRenderListener(new OnMapRenderListener() {
...
@Override
public void onPostDraw(boolean var1, long var2) {
}
..
```

Please note, any operations within the MapRender listener may block the UI thread hence should be used cautiously.